# Centrally align grids in material-ui react application

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, grid

I want to horizontally center Grid items inside a Grid container. Need some spacing between the Grid items as well. Please find the code below:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Container, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  topContainer: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(5),
  },
}));

export const AddContact = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Container fixed>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={3}
        alignContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        className={classes.topContainer}
      >
        <Grid item xs={4} style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }}>
          <TextField id="name" label="Name" style={{ width: "100%" }} />
          <TextField
            id="userName"
            label="User Name"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }}>
          STEP 2
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

The layout looks like below as of now.
[image]

The Grid items are not centrally aligned and there is no spacing between them as well. Could anyone please help me resolve.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving `alignContent="center"` provide `justify="space-around"` to the `<Grid>` container element. It'll align the items evenly and also separate them from each other according to the available space.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Container, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  topContainer: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(5),
  },
}));

const AddContact = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Container fixed>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={3}
        // alignContent="center"
        justify="space-around"
        alignItems="center"
        className={classes.topContainer}
      >
        <Grid item xs={4} style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }}>
          <TextField id="name" label="Name" style={{ width: "100%" }} />
          <TextField
            id="userName"
            label="User Name"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }}>
          STEP 2
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default AddContact
```

Here is the working sandbox link:- https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0sf86

You can try this also to play with grid alignment in `@material-ui`:- https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#interactive

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
  <Grid
    container
    spacing={2}
  >
     <Grid item md={4} lg={4}> </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4} style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }}>
      <TextField id="name" label="Name" style={{ width: "100%" }} />
      <TextField
        id="userName"
        label="User Name"
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4} style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }}>
      STEP 2
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```